# C Hash Table - Advantages/Disadvantages of Binary files?

Tags: c, hash, fwrite

I've been learning about hash tables and binary files recently and I was wondering how viable this method of data storage would be. Is it efficient to read/write to disk due to the added efficiency of binary files, or would this be considered inefficient? I've heard the term "hash to disk" mentioned more than once, but I was not sure if this would be for active data management as opposed to reading the dat file upon opening.

What are the advantages/disadvantages to storing data in a dat file rather than in memory?

For example I'm working on a program right now using a hash table to store my data. I can store my hash data to an array of struct, a linked list, or a binary file(the three methods I have learned thus far). If it is not so efficient to read/write from a file, is there still a situation which said method would be accepted?

Comment: The pretty obvious advantage of string data in a file as opposed in memory, is that the file will still be there when you terminate your program, and can be loaded again some other time.

Comment: I know writing in 'real time' would protect the data from a program crash. But of course there are other options such as a user initiated save. I'm wondering more about the active management of the data as the program is running - managing through modifying a data file vs using memory.

Comment: It depends entirely on what you want and what your use-cases are. Do you want speed? Do you want safety? Are multiple programs using your database simultaneously? Do you have so much data that it's not feasible to store all in memory? What kind of data do you want to store? What kind of *amounts* of data do you want to store? What is the expectations of the users of your program? What are *your* expectations of the program?

Comment: For any non-trivial program you should make a proper analysis with requirements and some use-cases, and then make a design from that. Not until that is done you should start writing code.

Comment: For most cases, I probably wouldn't bother maintaining the hash table in a file per se, unless the hash table needed to be a shared structure among multiple processes (memory mapped file). The hash table can be rebuilt on demand instead, and the file merely needs to journal the hash entries, not the hash table itself.